# Why does SelectionChanged bubble from ComboBox to parent TabControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, selectionchanged

After experiencing it myself, I did a quick search and found that SelectionChanged will bubble from a ComboBox to a parent TabControl if left unhandled in:

[In C# WPF, why is my TabControl's SelectionChanged event firing too often?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659858/in-c-wpf-why-is-my-tabcontrols-selectionchanged-event-firing-too-often)

My question is why? What is the reasoning behind this? I feel like I'm missing something pretty important about WPF and events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most events in WPF will bubble (or tunnel) until someone sets Handled=true on the event args.  The upside of this is that suppose you had multiple comboboxes within a single tab control - you could in a single place handle changes to all of those boxes.  You can do this in *addition* to handling the event seperately on each ComboBox or also handling a consolidated event even higher up in the tree like monitoring all ComboBoxes within the entire window.

This is what WPF calls "routed events".  For a good intro to the topic, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx